# Different phrase for “cash on delivery

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can say different phrase instead of cash on delivery as is the case with sentence below. I am asking if it is correct or not grammatically. As I am not a native speaker sometimes I couldn’t find correct phrase. For example  , Today I said this to an American native speaker and he understood me.

> He sent me package by cargo with payment that will be made by receiver.

Comment: What's wrong with "cash on delivery"?

Comment: Nothing. As I told you sometimes I couldn’t find best phrase. Would you understand me if say “ with payment that will be made by receiver”?

Comment: Sure, I'd understand, but I'd immediately suspect you're not a native speaker. Maybe I still don't understand your question. Now that you know the correct phrase, why not use it?

Answer (score 2):

> He sent me package by cargo with payment that will be made by receiver.

is intelligible, but sounds awkward.  People will understand exactly what you mean, but you will not sound like a fluent speaker.

The phrase "cash on delivery" or COD is idiomatic, and in American English we would always use it instead of some other words.   If you used other words, a listener might say "wait, let me make sure - you mean COD, right?"

If you must use different words, you might consider something like:

```
He shipped me the package by cargo to be paid upon receipt.
```

or

```
He shipped me the package by cargo pending payment.
```

Answer (score 1):

"Cash on delivery" is a common, stock phrase. If you use different words, the reader would likely interpret that to mean that you mean something other than cash on delivery. Like in this case, if you said, "payment will be made by receiver", they'd probably wonder if you meant that the receiver will pay for it, but not at the time that they receive it. That is, that they'll get a bill in the mail later. Or something like that.

In general, when there's a common word or phrase for some idea, and you intend to convey that idea, you should use the common word or phrase rather than trying to invent a new one. Otherwise, it leads the reader to think you must mean something else. Like if instead of saying, "Bob went to the hospital" you said "Bob went to a big building where they provide medical treatment", a reader would likely think you must mean some sort of medical facility that is not a hospital. Otherwise you would have just said "hospital".

Answer (score 0):

"Payment on receipt" is synonymous